# Pushing repo to remote repository (GitHub)

Tags: git, github, terminal, push

I'm new to Git/GitHub. Trying to push my files to a new repo I have set up and it's not working. Here's my process:

1. Set up repo on GitHub.
2. Initialise remote on repo. `git remote add origiN <URL>`
3. Check it's ok. `git remote -v`

This seems to all go to plan, as Terminal returns

```
origiN  <URL> (fetch)
origiN  <URL> (push)
```

...as expected.

Then, when I run `git push`, I get:

```
fatal: No configured push destination.
Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure a remote repository using

    git remote add <name> <url>

and then push using the remote name

    git push <name>
```

...but I thought I had already configured the remote repository?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

psydroyd answered whilst I was typing, but here is slightly more detail:

A repository can have multiple remotes.  You can push to a remote *explicitly* by running:

```
git push <remote> <branch>
```

But if you want `git push` to work without any additional parameters, you can use the `--set-upstream` option, aka `-u`, as in:

```
git push -u origin master
```

This sets up your local branch to track the remote `master` branch.  After this point, you can run:

```
git push
```

Comment: Thanks! Good to have the process explained.

Answer (score 2):

`git push -u origin master`

then you can just `git push`